# Optimise straight corners A* algorithm for pathfinding

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I'm working on the pathfinding for placing roads in a grid based RTS city building game, since I already used the A* algorithm for the pathfinding of vehicles I figured it would be convenient to use it for this task as well. Since our roads are just simple squares I couldn't use the original algorithm since the road would be like the picture: [Roadplacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYpLy.jpg)

The original algorithm checks every grid square next to it like this:

```
for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
            {
                if (x == 0 && y == 0))
                { continue; }
                //the rest of the code goes here
```

I figured the easiest way to avoid those diagonal placements was to block the option to use then, every grid square wouldn't check the 8 squares around it but just 4, in a plus sign:

```
for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
            {
                for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
                {
                    if ((x == 0 && y == 0)|| (x != 0 && y != 0))
                    { continue; }
                    //the rest of the code goes here
```

The only problem with this is that the time to find the path increases dramatically, I mean over large distances it jumps from 6 ms to ~70 ms. 
Does anyone have a solution that I could use, or a suggestion for another algorithm better suited for this kind of problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you adjust your heuristic to take into account that you've removed diagonal connectivity?

Comment: Following up on what harold said, your heuristic for this search should be something like `abs(destination_x - x) + abs(destination_y - y)` (i.e., "the Manhattan distance"). While your generation of points to test could be optimized a little, what you've changed should speed it up, because you are checking fewer points.

Comment: If your vehicles can move diagonally, your roads should be able to as well. The picture you showed makes it look ugly, but that's because you need tiles, with road on one side of the appropriate diagonal and landscape on the other, filling in the gaps. Essentially, you need to anti-alias your road.

Comment: My group and I decided that we only wanted the cars do drive in straight lines, along the x and y axis. I don't see how the distance calculation should be modified since its meant to be relative to the other gridsquares.

Comment: Banning diagonal movement in general increases distances, except in some special cases. Using a heuristic that now underestimates *more* than it used to (since it is same but the actual distance has gone up) means more tiles are explored.

Comment: I understand that it the computation time would slightly increase, but in this case the multiplication is a factor of 10-15. Even if it that was the main problem, would there be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XOR to optimize this line:

```
if ((x == 0 && y == 0)|| (x != 0 && y != 0))
```

by doing something like this:

```
if (!(x ^ y))
```

I'm not sure how much this will speed things up, but it's worth a shot!